# Seeking open source software for Coastal Flooding?

Tags: open-source

İs there any open source program that calculates coastal flooding by storm surge?

I calculated the sea level occured from storm surge.

I need a program that calculates which areas will be flooded by the sea level.

Comment: Welcome aboard! I am sorry that I can’t help you, but I thought that I would make you aware of our sister site https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ which might help you to get some of the data which you need. Good luck 